# Разделение таблицы на две колонки в зависимости от данных группы

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть исходная таблица с одной колонкой `V_GROUP`:

```
V_GROUP
------------------------------
1.1. Название группы 1  
1.1.1. Данные подгруппы 1   
1.1.2. Данные подгруппы 2   
1.1.3. Данные подгруппы 3   
1.2. Название группы 2  
1.2.1. Данные подгруппы 1 (2)   
1.2.2. Данные подгруппы 2 (2)   
1.2.3. Данные подгруппы 3 (3)
```

Из данной таблицы нужно сделать представление с 2 колонками `(V_SUBGROUP, V_GROUP)`, чтобы в левой колонке были подгруппы, а в правой - группы, и чтобы, конечно, правильные группы совпадали с подгруппами:

```
V_SUBGROUP                         V_GROUP
---------------------------------------------------------
1.1.1. Данные подгруппы 1       1.1. Название группы 1  
1.1.2. Данные подгруппы 2       1.1. Название группы 1  
1.1.3. Данные подгруппы 3       1.1. Название группы 1  
1.2.1. Данные подгруппы 1 (2)   1.2. Название группы 2
1.2.2. Данные подгруппы 2 (2)   1.2. Название группы 2
1.2.3. Данные подгруппы 3 (3)   1.2. Название группы 2
```

Comment: В общем то обычный join таблицы с самой собой. Только условие соединения сами придумывайте, потому как пытаться связать их по тексту `1.1.1` мягко говоря задача не для sql. у записей должны быть нормальные id и нормальные же ссылки на родителя по этим самым id ...

Comment: В этом и основная проблема.. Я думал их связать при помощи условия case when и сравнить по substr(v_group, 1, 3), но кроме долгих, почти "вручную" заносящихся запросов в голову ничего не приходит..

Comment: ну да, если цифр больше 9 нет, то можно substr(v_group, 1, 3) только дополнительно ограничить записи одного алиаса по `like '_._. %'` а второго по `like '_._._.%'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как правильно заметил [в комментарии @Мike](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1158247/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b-sql-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%bf%d1%8b#comment2009195_1158247), на этапе дизайна надо было предусмотреть деление записей на группы и подгруппы с указанием их связей. Раз это не произошло, а также учитывая, что иерархия записей только двухуровневая, то проще всего с *self-join*:

```
with q as (
    select grptxt, 
        regexp_substr (grptxt, '^((\d+)\.){2}') grpid2,
        regexp_substr (grptxt, '^((\d+)\.){3}') grpid3
    from t1)
select q3.grptxt subgrptxt, q2.grptxt 
from q q2
join q q3 on (
    q3.grpid2 = q2.grpid2 
    and q2.grpid3 is null 
    and q3.grpid3 is not null)
```

Даст желаемый результат:

```
SUBGRPTXT                        GRPTXT                          
-------------------------------- --------------------------------
1.1.1. Данные подгруппы 1        1.1. Название группы 1          
1.1.2. Данные подгруппы 2        1.1. Название группы 1          
1.1.3. Данные подгруппы 3        1.1. Название группы 1          
1.2.1. Данные подгруппы 1 (2)    1.2. Название группы 2          
1.2.2. Данные подгруппы 2 (2)    1.2. Название группы 2          
1.2.3. Данные подгруппы 3 (3)    1.2. Название группы 2
```

На [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8732e0965cc9d2ede86d6e2fe4882e1c).

Comment: Работает, спасибо (а так же остальным комментаторам, которые тоже помогли).

Answer (score 2):

Немного другая версия для Oracle. Повторное использование DDL из решения 0xdb. Спасибо.

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e817251a80dbb0b5ea6229bc9a6d94ab)

> pl/sql

```
WITH q as (
    SELECT substr(grptxt, 1, instr(grptxt, ' ', 1) - 1) AS hierarchy, grptxt
    FROM t1
)
SELECT p.grptxt as V_GROUP, c.grptxt as V_SUBGROUP
FROM q p LEFT OUTER JOIN q c 
   ON p.hierarchy = substr(c.hierarchy, 1, length(p.hierarchy))
WHERE length(p.hierarchy) < length(c.hierarchy);
```

> результат

```
+------------------------+-------------------------------+
|        V-GROUP         |          V_SUBGROUP           |
+------------------------+-------------------------------+
| 1.1. Название группы 1 | 1.1.1. Данные подгруппы 1     |
| 1.1. Название группы 1 | 1.1.2. Данные подгруппы 2     |
| 1.1. Название группы 1 | 1.1.3. Данные подгруппы 3     |
| 1.2. Название группы 2 | 1.2.1. Данные подгруппы 1 (2) |
| 1.2. Название группы 2 | 1.2.2. Данные подгруппы 2 (2) |
| 1.2. Название группы 2 | 1.2.3. Данные подгруппы 3 (3) |
+------------------------+-------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t2.v_group v_subgroup, t1.v_group
FROM test t1
JOIN test t2 ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.v_group, '.', 2) = SUBSTRING_INDEX(t2.v_group, '.', 2)
WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.v_group, '.', 3), '.', -1) LIKE ' %'
  AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t2.v_group, '.', 3), '.', -1) NOT LIKE ' %'
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f81d09d418502d37526848d18435a881)

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что для этого запроса нужно создать вторую таблицу, аналогичную первой?

Comment: @Gipnomanul Ну fiddle-то откройте да посмотрите, сколько там таблиц.

Comment: Да, вижу, спасибо. Только в правый столбец V_GROUP идет не та информация.

Comment: @Gipnomanul Опечатка. Поправил.